# I am unable to continuosly type in the input box in reactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mern

I have a component in which a input can be added and deleted multiple times.

```
<>
<form onSubmit={optimizeHandler}>
          <div className="filter-container">
            {conditions.map((condition, index) => {
              return (
                <PoolSize
                  onDeleteHandler={deleteCondition}
                  onChangeHandler={onChangeHandler}
                  onSelectHandler={onSelectConditionHandler}
                  key={index + "_optimise"}
                  d_key={index}
                  attributes={condattributes}
                  columns={selectedColumns}
                />
              );
            })}
          </div>
</>
```

This is the component code in this the PoolSize component code is below

```
<div className="container" name="Pool Size">
      <label id="label">Max Pool Amount is </label>
      <input
        id="pool_size"
        name="pool_size_number"
        type="number"
        placeholder="100000"
        key={d_key + "_pool_size_number"}
        onInput={(event) => onChangeHandler(d_key, event)}
        value={attributes.pool_size_number}
      ></input>
</div>
```

My onChange Handler code is

```
const onChangeHandler = (key, event) => {
    setConditions((prevConditions) => {
      let newCondition = [...prevConditions];
      const validatedValue = validateInput(
        event.target.name,
        event.target.value
      );
      newCondition[key].attributes[event.target.name] = validatedValue;
      return newCondition;
    });
  };
```

I have a conditions state in which a new object is added and delete and updated based on user updates.

Everything is working fine , except i cannot type continuosly in the input box . I am loosing the cursor once i type a number then i need to click once again to type.

Comment: In the PoolSize component, you may try to replace onInput with onChange.

Comment: Still the same issue

Comment: @Surya_1897 I was thinking of the same prop changes, but I see after 40 views nobody has seen anything else; so can you make a reproducible code snippet ([empty skeleton](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-new)). "*I am loosing the cursor once i type a number*" - what does  `onSelectConditionHandler` does?

Answer (score 0):

I was returning form from a method inside the component return , which will re-render the form everytime losing the focus. So moved the code inside the return to avoid re-renders.